# Problem with inserting a node at the end of LinkedList

Tags: c#

So I have a problem with this insertLast function in LinkedList.

```
public static void insertLast(LinkedList<Person> list, Person data)  
{ 
    LinkedListNode<Person> head= list.First;
    LinkedListNode<Person> rez = new LinkedListNode<Person>(data);

    if(head == null)  
    {  
        head = rez;   
        return;  
    }   
    LinkedListNode<Person> temp = head;    
    while (temp.Next != null)   
    {
        temp = temp.Next;    
    }  
    temp.Next = rez;  
}
```

I don't even know if this code will insert at the end because I can't test it because at this code `temp.Next = rez;` i get error:

*"Property or indexer 'LinkedListNode.Next' cannot be assigned to -- it is read-only."*

So if I understand `correctly.Next` is read-only so I can't use it like this. Now does anybody knows how to fix this?

I would really appreciate!

I can't use AddLast method because I have to create my own function.

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use AddLast? Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Here you can get ideas how it's internally implemented if you need to re-implement something:  https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/LinkedList.cs

Comment: I have the same question as @FabianBigler and had a comment in addition. If it is a homework assignment, is it not one to develop your own linked list class thus using your own implementation for InsertLast and anything else?

Comment: @FabianBigler yes it is for homework.

Comment: Create an array of `Person` call copy the values from `linkedList` to the created array, add the new element to the array, create a new `linkedList` and pass the array to the constructor.

Comment: You will have to create your own implementation of the node, as `LinkedListNode<T>.Next` is, as you've discovered, read only. There is nothing you can do about that. If your homework requires you to use this type *and* write to the `Next` property, go talk to your professor, because this is simply not possible.

Comment: @krneki Are you using the `LinkedList<>` and `LinkedListNode<>` classes from the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace or are these your own classes? When you use the classes from that namespace, why do you use them? It sounds more like you should create your own classes. Please [edit] your question to include your assignment, so we know what you should do based on the content of the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use AddLast()...but can you use AddAfter()?

```
    public static void insertLast(LinkedList<Person> list, Person data)
    {
        if (list.Count == 0)
        {
            list.AddFirst(data);
        }
        else
        {
            list.AddAfter(list.Last, data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are using the built-in `list.First`, can you use `list.Last` as well?

Answer (score -1):

Kindly, add this only two lines as below:

```
private void btnAddAtTheEnd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        treeView1.Focus();
        treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.Nodes[treeView1.Nodes.Count - 1];
    }
```

I hope it helps you ^_^

[image]